# How to display same content from API on every page in NuxtJS?

Tags: api, vue.js, nuxt.js

I’ve set up a NuxtJS app with a basic structure — header/nav, content, footer.
The data displayed in the footer will be retrieved from an API and displayed on every page.

How would you implement this in NuxtJS?

My first thought was to make a footer-component and `fetch` the API-data in there. This footer-component is included in the `default.vue`-layout, so that it’s displayed on every page.

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, this is exactly the way to go.

Something like this markup in your default layout, with some `asyncData` or `fetch` hook to populate your data once and you're good to go.

```html
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>{{ dynamicData }}</header> <!-- this will be present on every view -->

    <nuxt></nuxt> <!-- all of your pages will be there -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Then, in the nested pages, you will need to use `<nuxt-child></nuxt-child>`. Great thing is that it works great with some transitions. You could write this in a top level css file:

```css
.page-enter-active,
.page-leave-active,
.layout-enter-active,
.layout-leave-active {
  @apply transition-opacity duration-300;
}
.page-enter,
.page-leave-to,
.layout-enter,
.layout-leave-to {
  @apply opacity-0;
}
```